# BASH FOR loop using grep and awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, grep

I'm trying to get this script to `cat` a file and `grep` each line for `877` and for each line found, print the first column which is an IP and store it in hosts.  It get stuck on `awk` every time.  I run `sh -x some.sh` to see where it is hung up.  Should I print to a file instead of a list?  Why does it get stuck on `awk`?

```
hosts=()

FILENAME=/home/somethin/.hosts.conf

ips=`cat $FILENAME | grep -v '877'`

for line in $ips; do
     hosts=$(`awk '{print $1}'`)
done

echo $hosts
```

Comment: & To answer your question, "Why does it get stuck on awk?": You have not given any input to the awk command. `awk '{print $1}' <<< $line` was something, you would want. However, There is one more mess in your code: All the newlines, tabs etc have become single white-spaces & entire file has become a single line in `$ips`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can all be done using awk:

```
hosts=( $(awk '/877/{print $1}' $FILENAME) )

echo "${hosts[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava.  But I only get the first column of the first row.+ FILENAME=/home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf
+ hosts=($(awk '/332/{print $1}' $FILENAME))
++ awk '/332/{print $1}' /home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf
+ echo

Comment: Do you want rows containing 332 or rows not containing 332?

Comment: rows containing 332; there should be around 32 rows of ip addresses.

Comment: In that case try this command and let me know how many records you get in output: `awk '/332/{print $1}' /home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf` ?

Comment: no output: + awk '/332/{print $1}' /home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: ok what does `grep -c "332" /home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf` show?

Comment: grep -c "332" /home/occam/.blc-hosts.conf
0 --- it returned 0

Comment: this works on command line but not in my script: cat .blc-hosts.conf | grep 322 | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: If grep command is also showing 0 matches then obviously awk will show same. btw you want to match 332 or 322? Your last grep is showing 322 instead of 332?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this thread based on the original code, and a corrected version/code-review:

```
#ideally use variable names that do not exist as a command
hosts=()

FILENAME="/home/somethin/.hosts.conf"

ips=`cat $FILENAME | grep '322'`

for line in $ips; do
     hosts+=("`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`")
     #alternative for shells not supporting the += operator:
     #hosts=("${hosts[@]}" "`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`")
done

echo ${hosts[@]}
```

There are several issues to point out, that give you the impression your script is "*stuck on awk*"

- You are assigning host anew each time `` hosts=$(`awk '{print $1}'`) ``
- Intentionally or not, you are selecting the *inverse i.e. non-matches* with the grep flag `-v`.
- You are performing a nested command substitution in dollar and backtick notation, with input that doesn't contain commands: `$(`awk '{print $1}'`)` .
- awk is not given any input
- `echo variablename` will only print the first element of a bash array

Note: much can be performed with `awk` and `sed`, but both are rather intended as shortcuts to more verbose, but also better structured bash/shell skripts which are easier to extend later on. So there is a tradeoff, and there is nothing wrong in the way you started out with....

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`